# High-latency anonymous communication minimum delay?

Tags: web-application, privacy, anonymity

High-latency anonymous communication (e.g. Mixmaster and Mixminion) delay messages for a long time using mixers to anonymous communications. I understand that it has applications for email and p2p but not for good for responsive applications such as web browsing and instant messaging.

I've gone through the papers for them but couldn't find the relevant information.

1. How long exactly are the delays? minutes, hours, days?
2. Can these be set? is there a minimum bound for it to be defined as safe? I asked this because I'm wondering if it could be somehow applied to web browsing

Comment: Speculation: the required delay depends on the amount of traffic going through a relay. I would expect you could make anonymous web browsing that was resistant to traffic analysis, if you had a high volume of anonymous traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a paper, [Message Splitting Against the Partial Adversary](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/papers/pet05msgsplit.pdf),  on this topic, thanks to Prof. Murdoch.

For Mixminion, minimum delays seems to be 4.8 minutes and it is dependant on the numbers of messages into the mix.

[image]